# How to split a python dictionary into multiple dictionaries based on values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a dictionary of like:

```
{'A': [0, 2, 5],
 'B': [1],
 'C': [3, 6, 9],
 'D': [4, 7, 10],
 'E': [8, 11, 13],
 'F': [12]}
```

and I would like to split it into multiple dictionaries (say 2), based on the differences of consecutive elements in the values lists. For example, above:

```
dict_2 = {'A': [0, 2],
     'E': [11, 13]}

dict_3 = {'A': [2, 5],
     'C': [3, 6, 9],
     'D': [4, 7, 10],
     'E': [8, 11]}
```

So I compare consecutive values in each list, if the difference `(i+1) - i` is 2, I put it in `dict_2`, if it is 3, I put it in `dict_3`. I ignore the ones where there is only one element per list or the differences are other than 2 or 3.

I am trying a rather cumbersome approach:

```
def construct_dicts(init_dict, no_jumps=[2,3]):
    dct_2, dct_3 = {}, {}
    for key in init_dict.keys():
        for index in range(len(init_dict[key])):
            if init_dict[key][index+1] - init_dict[key][index] = no_jumps[0]:
                dct_2[key] = [index, index + 1]
            elif init_dict[key][index+1] - init_dict[key][index] = no_jumps[1]:
                dct_3[key] = [index, index + 1]
```

This however is cumbersome and ugly (and does not yet work). Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What if items in a list don't have same differences? Should they be in a separate group?

Comment: if the differences are neither 2 nor 3, they can be ignored.

Comment: Why 2 or 3? Is this part of the problem? Because there are many possibilities here. Please be more specific.

Comment: It is a constrained part of my problem. If you want to make it more general, then construct as many dictionaries as there are difference intervals, not just 2 or 3. That would be more difficult, but also useful in the long-run.

Comment: You should start by writing a function that produces lists `[0, 2]`, `[2, 5]` when given `[0, 2, 5]`, no list when given `[1]`, `[3, 6, 9]` when given `[3, 6, 9]`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general approach using a nested `collections.defaultdict`:

```
def categorize_dicts(dictionary):
    dfd = defaultdict(defaultdict)
    for k, v in d.items():
        for i,j in zip(v, v[1:]):
            dfd[j-i].setdefault(k,[]).extend((i, j))
    return dfd
```

Demo:

```
In [28]: d = {'A': [0, 2, 5],
        ...:  'B': [1],
        ...:  'C': [3, 6, 9],
        ...:  'D': [4, 7, 10],
        ...:  'E': [8, 11, 13],
        ...:  'F': [12, 15, 17],
        ...:  'T': [19]}
        ...:  

In [29]: categorize_dicts(d)
Out[29]: 
defaultdict(collections.defaultdict,
            {2: defaultdict(None, {'A': [0, 2], 'E': [11, 13], 'F': [15, 17]}),
             3: defaultdict(None,
                         {'A': [2, 5],
                          'C': [3, 6, 6, 9],
                          'D': [4, 7, 7, 10],
                          'E': [8, 11],
                          'F': [12, 15]})})
```

Comment: Not only did we choose the exact same approach, but also the exact same variable names =D

Comment: @a_guest Approaches are similar but not quite the same :)).

Comment: Sorry @a_guest, I have to choose Kasramvd's solution, since he beat you to it by 3 minutes. Thank you so much, both of you.

Comment: @Qubix No problem =D But note that Kasramvd's version currently contains duplicate values as opposed to the example you gave in the OP (e.g. `6` is duplicated for difference `3` and key `'C'`).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problem in your code:

1. `for index in range(len(init_dict[key]))` combined with `index + 1` will eventually result in `IndexError`.
2. You place the indices `index + 1, index` in the new list, instead of the corresponding list items.

This approach aims the address the above problems and to include a few improvements. It works for arbitrary differences and uses another `dict` to distinguish between them. Values are stored in a `set` in order to prevent duplicates from subsequent items with similar differences. If this is unintended then a `list` can be used with an additional check.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {
    'A': [0, 2, 5],
    'B': [1],
    'C': [3, 6, 9],
    'D': [4, 7, 10],
    'E': [8, 11, 13],
    'F': [12]
}
diff = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))

for k, v in d.items():
    for i, j in zip(v, v[1:]):
        diff[j-i][k] |= {i, j}
```

Comment: One question, if I also want other values than 2 and 3, how can I modify this, since I don't really understand how it works?

Comment: @Qubix It will create one `dict` per difference, no need to modify anything. In the end you can just select whatever differences you like, e.g. via `diff[2]` and `diff[3]`. Note that it requires the values in the original dict to be sorted though.